# Zooming in on a Canvas with + key and Zooming out with - key in Windows store apps?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, zooming

I am developing a Windows Store app.I have a canvas,on that i have to zoom in whenever user presses '+' key and zoom out on '-' key.And Zoom out should stop when canvas is in its original size.

It seems like there is no default way of doing that.

How can I do this?

I'll be very thankful for help.

Comment: put the canvas inside a  viewbox and increase the height and width of viewbox it automatically increase the size of each component

Comment: It is already inside a Viewbox.This is my current code.                                                                                                   <Viewbox Stretch="Fill" Height="560" Width="686">
                            <canvas:CanvasControl x:Name="canvas" Height="560" Width="686"
                              Draw="Canvas_Draw" />
                        </Viewbox>

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem before an i tried this

for zooming in or out

```
       delta = 1; // 0 for zoom out
        var transform = canvas.RenderTransform as MatrixTransform;

        var matrix = transform.Matrix;
        var scale = delta >= 0 ? 1.1 : (1.0 / 1.1); // choose appropriate scaling factor

        if (dt == null)
        {
            dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Delta", typeof(double));
            dt.Columns.Add("X", typeof(double));
            dt.Columns.Add("Y", typeof(double));

        }

        dt.Rows.Add(scale, position.X, position.Y);


        matrix.ScaleAtPrepend(scale, scale, position.X, position.Y);
        transform.Matrix = matrix;
```

---

for resetting to original

```
    for (int i = dt.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {

                var element = MainCanvas;
                var transform = element.RenderTransform as MatrixTransform;
                var matrix = transform.Matrix;

                var Delta = (double)dt.Rows[i]["Delta"] * -1;
                var scale2 = Delta >= 0 ? 1.1 : (1.0 / 1.1); //scale_ * 1;//e.Delta >= 0 ? 1.1 : (1.0 / 1.1); // choose appropriate scaling factor
                var X = (double)dt.Rows[i]["X"];
                var Y = (double)dt.Rows[i]["Y"];
                //matrix = transform_.Matrix;
                matrix.ScaleAtPrepend(scale2, scale2, X, Y);
                transform.Matrix = matrix;
                scale2 = 0;

            }

            dt = null;
```

in xaml

```
    <Canvas.RenderTransform>
        <MatrixTransform/>
    </Canvas.RenderTransform>
```

Comment: I'm pretty confused actually.On which event should i write this code?              And What is for Zoom in?

Comment: he first part will able you to zoom in and out  by changing the value of Delta for(+) delta = 1 / for(-) delta = 0, the zooming can be at any position you want by setting (position.x,position.y) and store every zoom(in/out) in datatable (dt)                                                                                                        the second part will undo every zoom you made by retrieving the values in dt in reverse and zoom in the opposite direction

Comment: But on which event do i need to add this?? And what is dt here??

Comment: try the first part with canvas_keyup() and set the value of delta to 1 if the key was (+) or 0 if the key was(-)

Comment: dt will save every zoom you made so if you want to return to initial run the second part

Comment: How do i initialize the dt?? I don't want to use a local DB.

Comment: What is delta??                                                                                         the code is giving error in delta and dt..?

Answer (score 0):

The `ScrollViewer` element has a built-in set of function to apply a zoom to its childs. So you can put your canvas inside one:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer" 
  MinZoomFactor="0.5" MaxZoomFactor="5" 
  VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled">
    <Canvas />
</ScrollViewer>
```

Then in your cs:

```
    public MainPage() {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown += Canvas_KeyDown;
    }

    private void Canvas_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
        var actual = scrollViewer.ZoomFactor;
        if (e.VirtualKey == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Add)
            scrollViewer.ChangeView(null, null, actual + 0.2f);
        else if (e.VirtualKey == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Subtract)
            scrollViewer.ChangeView(null, null, actual - 0.2f);
    }
```

You may need to know that if the user scroll with the wheel it will automatically change the zoom factor, as well as if a mobile/tablet user 'pinches' the canvas.

Comment: getting error in this line - Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown += Canvas_KeyDown;